# Difference between get cell value using row.Field<T>(col) and based on row/col index

Tags: c#, datatable, tostring

I'm new to c#, i had this script that was working perfectly

```
foreach(DataColumn col in dataTab.Columns){
 foreach(DataRow row in dataTab.Rows){
  row.Field<decimal>(col).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); }}
```

I had to use `ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` to be able to read the decimal separator. anyway, when i changed this code, looping on the rows/columns indexes and putting `dataTab[rowIndx][colIndx].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` i get an error in ToString method saying:

```
no overload for method tostring takes 1 argument
```

1. How can i fix this error?

2. why did it work in the first time and not in the second, what is the difference between the two methods?

Comment: First one you typed <decimal> so that's why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`row.Field<T>` is a generic method, you get back something strongly typed (`decimal` in your case), which has its own implementation of `ToString()`, including the overload that takes `CultureInfo` as parameter.

The second way using the indexes however, just gives you back an `object`. That's why you get the error, because `object.ToString()` does indeed not have an overload that takes 1 argument.

Answer (score 2):

```
row.Field<decimal>(col).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This line is revealed as decimal. Decimaltype has a ToString-overload accepting Cultureinfo.

```
dataTab[rowIndx][colIndx]
```

This line is revealed as object. Object does **not** have a ToString-overload accepting Cultureinfo.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers already covered the question #2

> why did it work in the first time and not in the second, what is the difference between the two methods?

Here is the answer to the question #1

> How can I fix this error?

You can use [Convert.ToString Method (Object, IFormatProvider)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131014(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Convert.ToString(dataTab[rowIndx][colIndx], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```